# relation of "radius of curvature" in a gaussian peak and the "sigma" for that gaussian shape

Tags: math

This is NOT about the radius of the kernel in gaussian blurring.

If it is given the radius of curvature for the peak of a gaussian shaped paraboloid, how can I calculate the sigma, which would draw such paraboloid?
And vice versa: if I have a gaussian shaped paraboloid, which I draw according to a certain sigma, how can I know the radius of curvature for the peak I see in that paraboloid?

What is a simple conversion formula between radius of curvature and sigma? At least some approximation?

Some really easy to understand (maybe approximating) formula, for a know-nothing in math guy?

Comment: This is, as a question about pure math, completely off-topic. Take it to math.stackexchange and clarify the geometry of the question, the curvature depends on the scaling of the value axis. It might help to give some background, if any serious background exists, as it is the question is rather artificial.

Comment: Sorry, I didn´t know that math.stackexchange exists. There is alwasys something new to discover! Thought that tagging my question with the only tag "math" would be sufficient to clarify that it is only about math.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible to calculate radius of curvature of gaussian peak with sigma given (in the top point) with [curvature formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Curvature&section=5#Curvature_of_a_graph) (note that `Radius = 1 / k`). This is Maple output (sigma=s, mu=0, yy is the first derivative of Gaussian, yyy is the second derivative):
[image]

This formula is rather complex, but when we substitute x with 0,

```
R = sqrt(2*Pi) * sigma^3
```

and

```
sigma = (R / sqrt(2*Pi))^(1/3)
```

Quick check (sigma=0.3 and 0.6). Blue - gaussian, black - circles with calculated radii.

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot, it works nicely and helped me! I learned from it that there is a "noramlization constant" involved, which so far wasn´t in my little MATLAB code. I am now trying to figure out how to take into account scaling of the value axis and sample axis. So far I didn´t find any simple soluition. For the case somebodey would also know how to include this, I would be interested to see! I think I will open a new thread in math.stackoverflow about this follow up problem, if I don´t find my own solution fiddling a day or two more around. Thanks again, MBo, your answer already helped me a lot!!

Comment: I've used scale value 400 for both axes to draw these graphs in proper size (to avoid circle distortion into ellipse).